# bluetooth error on recovery from suspend, 18.04

Tags: suspend, bluetooth, dell, pulseaudio, xps

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS-13 (9350). In order to get the bluetooth working I have to use a proprietary driver (BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd), extracted from a windows driver.

Everything works fine and I'm able to pair all of my devices. However when I wake from suspend, bluetooth headsets won't pair any more. Or more correctly, they pair and then immediately lose connection. This is what shows up in the syslog:

```
Jul  6 09:19:33 user-XPS-13-9350 pulseaudio[6302]: [pulseaudio] backend-native.c: Device     doesnt exist for /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_E0_E4_6D_1B_CD
Jul  6 09:19:33 user-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[957]: Headset Voice gateway replied with an      error: org.bluez.Error.InvalidArguments, Unable to handle new connection
```

I found the following things that would restore bluetooth functionality:

- Full reboot (obviously not ideal solution)
- Restart pulseaudio (run `pulseaudio -k`). This is better, but when I restart pulseaudio, a lot of apps like Chrome need to be restarted also, because they lose their list of audio input/output devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started playing around with unloading/reloading modules in pulseaudio and discovered that I can fix the problem without completely killing pulseaudio. Just reloading the `module-bluez5-discover` module fixes it.

```
pactl unload-module module-bluez5-discover
pactl load-module module-bluez5-discover
```

If I run this after waking from suspend, everything works fine. And even if I try to pair and get the error, running this will fix the problem right away.

It also doesn't have the problems with requiring Chrome/Electron apps to be restarted.